# File reader configuration doesn't work for Fume

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Iam new to flume and was trying my first experiment with it.Iam trying to read data from a file using fume and send it to a kafka topic.

The configuration is pulled from a tutorial [website](https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-data-ingestion-with-apache-flume-sending-ev).The configuration is shown below.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = sample 
a1.channels = sample-channel

a1.sources.r1.type = exec
a1.sources.r1.command = tail -f \data.txt 
a1.sources.r1.logStdErr = true
a1.channels.sample-channel.type = memory
a1.channels.sample-channel.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.sample-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
a1.sources.r1.channels = sample-channel
a1.sinks.sample.topic = sample
a1.sinks.sample.brokerList = 127.0.0.1:9092
a1.sinks.sample.requiredAcks = 1
a1.sinks.sample.batchSize = 20
a1.sinks.sample.channel = sample-channel
```

But this doesnot do anything.It isn't throwing any errors,but a few warnings. The log is shown below.

```
2020-12-03 12:01:17,265 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateConfigFilterSet(FlumeConfiguration.java:623)] Agent configuration for 'a1' has no configfilters.
2020-12-03 12:01:17,291 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSinks(FlumeConfiguration.java:884)] Could not configure sink  sample due to: Component has no type. Cannot configure. sample
org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: Component has no type. Cannot configure. sample
        at org.apache.flume.conf.ComponentConfiguration.configure(ComponentConfiguration.java:76)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.sink.SinkConfiguration.configure(SinkConfiguration.java:44)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSinks(FlumeConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeConfiguration.java:383)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.access$000(FlumeConfiguration.java:228)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:153)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.<init>(FlumeConfiguration.java:133)
        at org.apache.flume.node.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.getFlumeConfiguration(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:194)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:97)
        at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:145)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, r1 has no type, so it doesn't know what to do with your source

You're missing

```
a1.sources.r1.type = exec
```

Personally, I'd suggest Filebeat or Telegraf over Flume for taking files to Kafka

Comment: I have added the edits you mentioned but a new error is coming up now. I have updated the question with your suggestions and logfile has been changed.

Comment: Same issue, a1.sinks.sample.type is missing

Comment: Added that whole errors are gone. But the data is not comming to Kafka topic.

Comment: There's some caveat with using tail and exec sources, I believe (again, mentioned in the User Guide). The proper solution is to use the spooldir source

Comment: Could also be that \data.txt is not a proper file path. And if you're using Windows, tail isn't a command

Comment: I installed the UnxUtils for Windows to get around the tail issue

Comment: Spooling diretory did the job